# Creating two arrays containing an original array with different values added at the end

Tags: ruby, arrays

So I am trying to build a multidimensional array by starting with a single array and splitting it into separate arrays to account for possible added values.

Example:

Original Array: `[2,3]`

adding either 4 or 5

New array: `[[2,3,4],[2,3,5]]`

I have tried the following:

```
array=[2,3]
array1=array<<4
array2=array<<5

array=[2,3]
array1=array<<4
array.pop
array2=array<<5

array=[2,3]
array1=array.push 4
array.pop
array2=array.push 5
```

The results I get are:

```
[[2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5]]
[[2,3,5],[2,3,5]]
[[2,3,5],[2,3,5]]
```

Is there a way to alter the original array only in the new variables so that the variables don't end up equal when I combine them?

Comment: `array1 = array + [4]; array2 = array + [5]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of methods on Array that are in-place modifiers, that is they don't make copies, and `<<` is one of them.

What you might find easier is this:

```
array = [ 2, 3 ]
array1 = array + [ 4 ]
array2 = array + [ 5 ]
```

The result in this case is two independent arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Another interesting way to do this is using the [splat](https://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/) operator:

```
array = [2, 3]
array1 = [*array, 4]
# => [2, 3, 4]
array2 = [*array, 5]
# => [2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: ...which lends itself nicely to mapping an array of values to add to `array`.  Nice.

Answer (score 0):

If you have several times to add to:

```
array = [1, 2, 3]
```

say:

```
b = [*(4..20)]
  #=> [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

you could use the method [Array#product](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-product):

```
[array].product(b).map(&:flatten)
  #=> [[1, 2, 3,  4], [1, 2, 3,  5], [1, 2, 3,  6], [1, 2, 3,  7],
  #    [1, 2, 3,  8], [1, 2, 3,  9], [1, 2, 3, 10], [1, 2, 3, 11],
  #    [1, 2, 3, 12], [1, 2, 3, 13], [1, 2, 3, 14], [1, 2, 3, 15],
  #    [1, 2, 3, 16], [1, 2, 3, 17], [1, 2, 3, 18], [1, 2, 3, 19],
  #    [1, 2, 3, 20]]
```

Comment: Thanks, that may be helpful I will have to play with the #product method to make sure I understand it.